# Longitudinal CFA How to build configural model?

Tags: r, confirmatory-factor

I have 12 survey questions (Qs) that were asked during pre- and post-term survey. So I want to do the longitudinal CFA to see whether there was a difference between factor models for pre/post-term surveys

12 survey questions are broken down into 3 latent variables:

Anx =~ Q1 + Q2 + Q3 + Q4

Bel =~ Q5 + Q6 + Q7 + Q8

Eff =~ Q9 + Q10 + Q11 + Q12

so the same questions were asked in pre and post-term surveys.

I was wondering about how to build the configural model :

1. Model each factor separately for pre and post-term:

   ```
   overall.model.Bel <- '
   Bel.pre =~  Q1.pre+ Q2.pre+ Q3.pre+ Q4.pre
   Bel.post =~  Q1.post+ Q2.post+ Q3.post+ Q4.post
   '

   overall.model.Anx <- '
   Anx.pre =~  Q1.pre+ Q2.pre+ Q3.pre+ Q4.pre
   Anx.post =~  Q1.post+ Q2.post+ Q3.post+ Q4.post
   '

   overall.model.Eff <- '
   Eff.pre =~  Q1.pre+ Q2.pre+ Q3.pre+ Q4.pre
   Eff.post =~  Q1.post+ Q2.post+ Q3.post+ Q4.post
   '
   ```
2. Or I should do it all at ones:

   ```
   overall.model.Bel <- '

   Bel.pre =~  Q1.pre+ Q2.pre+ Q3.pre+ Q4.pre
   Bel.post =~  Q1.post+ Q2.post+ Q3.post+ Q4.post

   Anx.pre =~  Q1.pre+ Q2.pre+ Q3.pre+ Q4.pre
   Anx.post =~  Q1.post+ Q2.post+ Q3.post+ Q4.post

   Eff.pre =~  Q1.pre+ Q2.pre+ Q3.pre+ Q4.pre
   Eff.post =~  Q1.post+ Q2.post+ Q3.post+ Q4.post
   '
   ```
3. any other things I should add or modify?

Then build the model

```
overall.fit <- cfa(model = overall.model,
                   data = master, 
                   meanstructure = TRUE)
```

4. Also, out of curiosity, can I use `library(equaltestMI)`  to do longitudinal CFA? or that one is only for multigroup CFA ( I am not entirely sure what is the difference in the steps between two, except that for multigroup one the groups are independent of each other)